# MapKit annotation IOS 5 don't showing

Tags: ios, objective-c

i create custom annotation for map view.
When i place pin on the map showing annotation with 2 buttons.
it's work for ios 6, but when i test this code in ios 5, i can't see any annotation.

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id         <MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;  //return nil to use default blue dot view
NSLog(@"viewForAnnotation");
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 

    initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"loc"];
annotationView.draggable = YES;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button setTitle:@"Добавить" forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];

button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 76, 23);
 if (plased == YES){
     annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;
 }

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(fixPoint:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];


UIButton *buttonLeft = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[buttonLeft setTitle:@"Удалить" forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
buttonLeft.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 66, 23);
[buttonLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelPoint:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
if (plased == YES){
    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = buttonLeft;
}
annotationView.tag = [geoPointsList count]+1;
annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

return annotationView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I put here Simple Example For how to Create Custom AnnotationView.**

Create custom `AnnotationView`:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface AnnotationView : MKPlacemark

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subtitle;

// you can put here any controllers that you want. (such like UIImage, UIView,...etc)

@end
```

And in `.m file`

```
#import "AnnotationView.h"

@implementation AnnotationView

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate addressDictionary:(NSDictionary *)addressDictionary
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:addressDictionary]))
    {
        self.coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

// Use Annotation Add `#import "AnnotationView.h"` in your relevant `.m file`:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pCoordinate ;
pCoordinate.latitude = LatValue;
pCoordinate.longitude = LanValue;

// Create Obj Of  AnnotationView class  

AnnotationView *annotation = [[AnnotationView alloc] initWithCoordinate:pCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] ;

    annotation.title = @"I m Here";
    annotation.subtitle = @"This is Sub Tiitle";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```